# Get only month(in short) and date in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

i have some date in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" format and want to get just the month and date.
How can i format it in kotlin?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `SimpleDateFormat` as it's [outdated and troublesome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api)

Use `LocalDateTime` to format the date.

```
val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
val dateTime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter)
```

Use `DateTimeFormatter` if you want your date in different format

```
val formatter2: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MMM")
Log.e("Date 3 ", dateTime.format(formatter2))
```

Or if you want date and month values from the date object use `dayOfMonth` and `monthValue`

```
Log.e("Date 3 ", "Date ${dateTime.dayOfMonth} , Month ${dateTime.monthValue}")
```

**Note**: `LocalDateTime` only works in android 8 and above, to use it below android 8 enable [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring)

In your app module's `build.gradle`, add `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled`

```
compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert date from one format to other format.

Try below code to convert date string one format to other format:

```
@Throws(ParseException::class)
    fun convertDateInString(dateTime: String?, inputFormat: String?, outputFormat: String?): String? {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat, Locale.US)
        val date = sdf.parse(dateTime)
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat, Locale.US)
        return simpleDateFormat.format(date)
    }
```

In Activity or Fragment class:

```
var date = "2022-01-10 10:00:00.2"
var convertDate = convertDateInString(date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", "dd-MM")
```